# Betrayal at House on the Hill: Haunt 2: The Séance

Tags: betrayal-at-house-on-the-hill

During the Séance Haunt, the hero's summoned the Ghost and started traveling around to complete their quest.

The traitor then, attacked and killed the Hero who completed the Séance.

Does this mean the Hero's fail their quest because the Turn/Damage track can no longer progress?

The rules say, "Set up the Turn/Damage track with a plastic clip on 1. At the end of each subsequent turn of the player who completed the Séance, advance the clip to the next number on the track. You have until the start of the Turn 5 to bury the Ghost's bones."

Answer (score 4):

For the heroes, there are two ways to win:

> they either defeat the ghost after the traitor takes control of it, or they burry the ghost's bones after they summon it.

They have 5 turns to find and bury the bones. The track marker advances after the players turn. If that hero is dead but other hero's are alive, you just advance the marker at the time the dead hero should have had his or her turn.

So no the heroes only lose if the last one of them died.